# A vector space over an infinite field is not a finite union of proper subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Show that if $V$ is a vector space over an infinite field $\mathbb{F}$, then $V$ cannot be written as
set-theoretic union of a finite number of proper subspaces.

Comment: Is your original vector space finite-dimensional?

Comment: It would be helpful for the people who would want to help out for them to know what your trouble is and what has gone wrong with your attempts

Answer (score 21):

By contraposition: if $V$ is the set-theoretic union of $n$ proper subspaces $W_i\,$ ($1\le i\le n$), then $\lvert\mkern2mu F\,\rvert\le n-1$.

*Proof*. We may suppose no $W_i$ is contained in the union of the other subspaces. Let $u\in W_i,\enspace u\notin \bigcup\limits_{j\neq i}W_j$ and $v\notin W_i$.

Then $(v+Fu)\cap W_i=\varnothing$ and $(v+Fu)\cap W_j\enspace(j\neq i)$ contains *at most one* vector since otherwise $W_j$ would contain $u$. Hence
$$\lvert\mkern2mu v+ Fu\, \rvert=\lvert\mkern2mu F\,\rvert\le n-1.$$

*Corollary: Avoidance lemma for vector spaces.*

Let $E$ be a vector space over an infinite field. If a subspace is contained in a finite union of subspaces, it is contained in one of them.

*Note:* There exists a similar (and better known) *Avoidance lemma* for prime ideals in commutative rings.

Comment: well done 'I like the proof

Answer (score 4):

If your original vector space is finite-dimensional, say dimension $d$, then consider the vectors that lie on the power curve $(1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\ldots,\alpha^{d-1})$ where $\alpha$ is an arbitrary element in your field. Show that all of these vectors are distinct for distinct $\alpha$ in your field and that any $d$ of them generate your entire vector space if your vector space is $d$-dimensional. (Hint: Vandermonde determinant). Then if your space is a union of finitely many subspaces, one of them must contain infinitely many vectors on the power curve so...

Comment: Sorry I have not understood the concept of vectors to lie on the power curve. That $d $ tuple are entries from field. Now will you explain a bit more? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $V \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n V_i$.  In the infinite-dimensional situation, reduce to the finite dimensional situation by choosing one vector $v_i$ from each $V\setminus V_i$.  Then intersect all spaces with $\text{span}(v_1,\dots,v_n)$.  The hypothesis are still satisfied (and even $V = \bigcup V_i$ now), but we can assume all involved spaces to be finite-dimensional.

For each $V_i$ choose a linear form (the coefficients are "normal vector") that vanishes on $V_i$.  The product of those linear forms is a degree $n$ polynomial that vanishes on $V$ which is a contradiction $-$ over an infinite field the zero polynomial is the only polynomial that vanishes on all of $V$.