# If a vector subspace is in a union of other subspaces, then it's contained in one of them

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Problem:** Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and $V_1,\ldots,V_n\subset V$ vector subspaces. Show that if $W\subset V$ is a vector subspace and
>   $$W\subset V_1\cup\cdots\cup V_n,$$
>   then
>   $$W\subset V_k$$
>   for some $1\le k\le n$.

I get the intuitive idea of why this should hold by drawing pictures, but I can't prove it rigorously. I know that if $V_1,V_2$ are two subspaces and $V_1\cup V_2$ is also a subspace, then $V_1\subset V_2$ or $V_2\subset V_1$. Does that help?

Comment: I think you must be making an assumption about the underlying field; this isn't true for finite fields. Are you thinking of vector spaces over $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @joriki $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$.

Comment: @joriki: It's true for finite fields under an assumption on the cardinality  of the field. See my answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1165705/a-vectorspace-over-an-infinite-field-is-not-a-finite-union-of-proper-subspaces/1186139#1186139).

Comment: @Bernard: Well, that assumption depends on $n$; I meant that it isn't true for general $n$ as stated, and indeed there's no finite field for which it's true for all $n$.