# Exercise similar to prime avoidance theorem in R.Y. Sharp's textbook

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I'm a beginner in commutative algebra, and I'm self-studying this subject via R.Y. Sharp's textbook.

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$ which contains an infinite field as a subring. Let $I$ and $J_1,\ldots,J_n$ where $n\ge2 $, be ideals of $R$ such that:
>
> $$I\subseteq J_1\cup J_2\cup\cdots\cup J_n.$$
>
> Prove that $I \subseteq J_j$ for some $j$ with $1\le j \le n$.

It looks similar to the Prime Avoidance Theorem, but in this case each $J_i$ just to be ideals and I can't figure out what the role of *"contains an infinite field as a subring"* in this situation.

I expect for some idea / suggestion. Thank in advance.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1165705/a-vector-space-over-an-infinite-field-is-not-a-finite-union-of-proper-subspaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: The ring $R$ can be thought of as vector space over the infinite field. Then prove that a vector space is not a finite union of subspaces.

Comment: Well, a vector space can be a *finite* union of subspaces, but not when the field is infinite.

Comment: yeah,in the case infinite field I use pigeonhole principle to enter the contradiction.