# Ideals in Commutative Rings Containing a Field

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

This is a question that always stumped me.  It is from an undergrad book (Sharp, Steps in Commutative Algebra) and apparently concerns the Primary Decomposition/Prime Avoidance Theorem, so I expect the solution to be only a few lines, but I can't get it.

Suppose that $R$ is a commutative ring containing an infinite field $F$.  Suppose that $I, J_1, \dots, J_n$ are ideals of $R$.  Suppose that $I \subset \bigcup\limits_n J_n$.  Then prove that $I$ is contained in some $J_k$.

I can't figure out how to use the presence of the field to turn it into a situation where the Prime Avoidance Theorem can be applied, but maybe this isn't the right method.

Comment: I'm sure this is what you meant, but for the sake of avoiding pedantry you should mention that $ F $ is a subring, not just contained in $ R $.

Comment: Are $\{J_i\}_{i=1}^n$ all prime ideal?

Comment: This is because $R, I,J_1,\dots,J_n\: $ are also $F$-vector (sub)spaces, and we have the *Avoidance lemma for subspaces*.

For a proof, please see my answer to [A vector space over an infinite field is not a finite union of proper subspaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1165705/a-vector-space-over-an-infinite-field-is-not-a-finite-union-of-proper-subspaces/1186139#1186139)