# How to find a vector such that the inner product is not zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vectors

Let $V$ be a finite set consist of nonzero vectors $v=(v_1, \cdots, v_n)\in \mathbb{Z}^n$, how to find a vector $w\in \mathbb{Z}^n$ such that the inner product $<w,v>$ is nonzero for any $v\in V$?

Comment: You should be more explicit.  For example, should $w$ also belong to $V$ ? Or can $w$ be an arbitrary vector from $\mathbb N^n$?

Comment: Do you mean $\langle w,v\rangle\ne 0$ for all $v\in V$?

Comment: @xyz Well, in my case I need $w\in \mathbb{Z}^n$

Comment: @JohnDouma Yes! for all vectors in $V$.

Comment: In some sense, "most" $w$ will have this property. It follows from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1165705/473276), for example (at least assuming that $0 \notin V$!)

Comment: Wouldn't $[-1 \quad {-}1 \quad \cdots \quad {-}1]$ work? Or $[1 \quad 1 \quad \cdots \quad 1]$ for that matter?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Thank you, but I don't see how my question relate to your link? could you please give me some hint?

Comment: @BrianTung I'm sorry that my statement is not correct, $v\in \mathbb{Z}^n$ and in my case I don't know what these vectors look like. So I only need the existences of $w$.

Comment: As I understand it, you're asking "given a finite set of nonzero vectors in $\Bbb Z^n$, must there always be some vector which is not orthogonal to any of them?" You should show that this is equivalent to the same statement over $\Bbb Q^n$, and that if $v$ is a nonzero vector in $\Bbb Q^n$, then the set of vectors orthogonal to $v$ is a proper $\Bbb Q$-linear subspace.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the case $n=1$, we can choose $w=(1)$. We build up to any $n$ from there.

Consider $V'$, formed by discarding the last element of each element of $V$; eg given $v \in V$, $v' \in V'$ is $(v_1, v_2, \dots, v_{n-1})$.

Suppose you have $w' \in \mathbb R^{n-1}$ that satisfies $\left<w',v'\right> \ne 0 \forall v' \in V'$. Let $m=\max_{v' \in V'} |\left<w',v'\right>|$ (the biggest inner product).

Let $w_n=m+1$. We then have $\left<w,v\right>=\left<w',v'\right> + (m+1) v_n$.

For $v$ with $v_n=0$, the inner product is unchanged: $\left<w,v\right>=\left<w',v'\right>\ne 0$.

Otherwise, $|v_n| \geq 1$; therefore, $|(m+1) v_n| > m$. Since $|\left<w',v'\right>| \leq m$, the sum $\left<w,v\right>=\left<w',v'\right> + (m+1) v_n \ne 0$.

Comment: Thank you! this is what I want